# What impact do the "dislikes" have on your favorability to employers?

Tags: discussion, jobs

So I'm just wondering if I should put anything under the dislikes section.  Right now I have "windows" under there because I'd don't like using windows.  However, when it comes to employment, I'll do what is necessary and I believe in using the right tool for the job.

However, what about a programming language that I don't like much but I'm experienced in it and will take a job using it if necessary?  If I were being honest I would put that in my dislikes section but would that make those types of employers not want to contact me?

I guess it seems to me like having skill levels would be more useful.  So what technologies are you an expert in, intermediate, or just a beginner?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't put anything down unless you were perfectly ok with a potential employer crossing you off their list because you "dislike" their pet technology. If in doubt, leave it off. However, of course only the employers can really provide accurate answers to you about how this impacts them...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I generally agree with most of the answers here that dislikes should be employed only if they are deal breakers, but consider that **dislikes can be used strategically to enhance your CV**.

While it will turn some people off, those with strong opinions often get noticed, especially by others with strong opinions - notably type A personalities that enjoy climbing the corporate ladder, or in other words your hiring manager/boss.

**Lukewarm**

If you like a lot of things, and dislike nothing, it may mean that you are simply a well rounded developer that believes the right tool should be used for the right job.  It could also mean that you won't speak up if the wrong decision is being made, that you waffle, and that you are a 'lukewarm' programmer that hasn't had enough experience to know what's really, truly bad.

**Type A personalities**

Alternately, you can use it to appeal to those with strong opinions.  Guess what - there's a strongly vocal group of people that loathe VB.  Of course this hatred comes from the early days of VB, but that won't stop them from hating basic in general and VB in particular.  It may not hurt you to add VB as a dislike (although if you work with .NET you might want to reconsider).

**Expertise**

Further, it can show them that you have enough expertise in a language, technology, or framework to really hate it.

I don't think you'll get many blank stares if you mention that you dislike cobol, fortran, or even MFC and it will make an interesting interview topic as you discuss the projects you've worked on where the language, technology, or framework itself proved an impediment to good development practices.

**Don't treat that field lightly, but don't discount it out of hand either.**

Comment: +1 for HATING VB. I hate old VB, and modern VB.net. It's not about the language... its about the SYNTAX and how it makes my brain want to will itself to die, and make me punch myself in the face, or a baby

Comment: http://wyolife.com/kerryfest/BabyPunch.jpg and http://rlv.zcache.com/baby_punch_tshirt-p235428556053938600qmkd_400.jpg are relevant to your comment.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it provides much more strategy and caused me to put some things in my dislikes section.  If I start getting desperate for work I'll probably take them out but let's see how it goes.

Answer (score 10):

It says in the pop up help for "dislikes" that they are *deal breakers*. If you **would** consider working with the technology, I'd say it doesn't belong in that box.

If you honestly would rather find work as a taxicab driver than write another web site using Perl CGI, then what do you lose by letting employers know that?

Anything that requires more context probably belongs in the personal statement or background boxes.

Answer (score 4):

The `Dislikes` is an area that I have nothing published on.

Yea, I dislike PHP, but I know it and I'll program in it if necessary.

The old adage, `"If you don't have anything nice to say, don't say anything at all."` applies doubly to your CV.

Putting 'dislikes' is almost as bad as saying: `"I have no pathologies that keep me from working with others."`

Yes, I have seen that statement in a Stack Overflow CV.

Answer (score 4):

One way to use the dislikes field is to put things that people will obviously agree with you on.

**Dislikes:** Inefficiency, Poor Communication, Rotten Food, Murder

---

On a more serious note... I'd remove Windows from your dislikes if you will tolerate it to get the job done.

Since you cannot really quantify your dislike for it, one potential employer may see that as:

> "Oh man! This guy must be one of those
>   Winders hatin' Eunichs Nazis!"

while another may see it as:

> "I dislike Windows as well, but
>   tolerate it. Sounds like a solid guy"

However, I would submit that the former is much more likely to occur given Windows' (dwindling) market share.

Answer (score 4):

My theory is that the only thing that belongs in <kbd>dislikes</kbd> are things you truly ***WILL NOT*** use.

If you're going to "tolerate" something, it's a preference, not a "dislike".

If you won't do it, then put it down. I won't do Java. I happen to be able to read (and even write [sometimes]) Java, but I won't work with it. I'll do PHP, Python, bash, C - but not Java. That's me. (I'm also more sysadmin-y than programmer-y.)

I can learn anything, but what I won't work with I feel should be listed. But only what I **won't** work with.

Comment: Agreed about Java -- one of the best career moves I made was not learning it (beyond rudimentary "hello world" levels), as it totally precluded me ever accidentally getting a job using it :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be limited to things you **WILL NOT** work in, and don't want to be bothered with.  For example I have COBOL and Assembly listed in the `dislikes` section of my yet unpublished CV, because in fact I will not work in either, and I don't want to be bothered with them.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Snicker's answer, I've attempted to add some humor to my CV by putting *homework* as a dislike. Maybe if you could find some other tags that your targeted employers would find humorous you could do something similar. http://careers.stackoverflow.com/json